# php session variable multidimensional associative array issue

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, session-variables, associative-array

I've looked around SO, but can't find an explanation to what is going on in my $_SESSION variables.

```
@ob_start();
$k=@ob_get_contents();
@ob_end_clean();
@session_start();
unset($s,$m);
$m1 = explode(" ", microtime());
$stime = $m1[1] + $m1[0];
echo $k;

$_SESSION['resendConfirmation']['function'] = 'resend';
$_SESSION['resendConfirmation']['id'] = '8';                

print_r($_SESSION);
```

outputs:

```
Array ( [resendConfirmation] => 8esend )
```

Why is it string replacing?  I've never had this issue before.

What I want is thus:

```
Array([resendConfirmation] => Array(
                             [id] =>8
                             [function} => resend
                             )
)
```

I've never had this happen before, I'm totally confused!

***UPDATE***
In response to @DanRedux I've changed to two non-existent variable names to take the referencing out of the equation, still the same result...

```
$_SESSION['resendConfirmation']['tweak'] = 'resend';
$_SESSION['resendConfirmation']['tweak2'] = '8';
```

Same result :(

Did a sitewide query of `resendConfirmation` and none were found, but once I change that array name, it all worked, baffled, but fixed...

```
$_SESSION['reConfirm']['function'] = 'resend';
$_SESSION['reConfirm']['id'] = '8';             

print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Please fix the first line of your code so that it's readable.

Comment: First line is actually not needed. However, this is a really strange but cool question.. `$_SESSION['resentConfirmation']['id']` is somehow referring to the first index, that's why the first character is changing, so why would ['id'] refer to [0].. Maybe you set it by reference at some point?

Comment: Don't abuse the use of `@`, it suppresses warnings you might care about and has a pretty hefty performance hit. None of the functions in your code should misbehave if you check your inputs properly. There are some exceptions where `@` is useful but even then it's dubious.

Comment: PHP 5.3.8 returns `Array ( [resendConfirmation] => Array ( [function] => resend [id] => 8 ) )`

Comment: the session initialization (the first 8 lines) has been used throughout the project.  I don't have this issue anywhere else...

Comment: Seriously, you could check data type with `error_log('$var type: '.gettype($var));` while debugging. Always good to know what you really have to avoid this kind of problems. Often forgotten that `[]` is not same as array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I dont really know what other sorts of shenanigans the code is up to outside of this block you gave us I would say to just try this instead:

```
$_SESSION['resendConfirmation'] = array('id' => 8, 'function' => 'resend');
```

If this also fails then there has to be something else going on outside of what you posted. Good luck!

Comment: not sure what was going on, but there must have been some reference to resendConfirmation somewhere.  renamed, and all worked.

Answer (score 6):

What you think is an multidimensional array really isn't. What really happens is:

What you think is an array is really a string. After that you are trying to access the string as an array. You are trying to access the element `id` which doesn't exists. PHP always tries to be smarter than it should and just says: OK I'll assume you meant the first index. So basically what happens is:

```
<?php
$notAnArray = 'somestring';
$notAnArray['id'] = '8'; 

var_dump($notAnArray); // 8omestring
```

This is the reason you [should *always* enable error_reporting](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jottbA) on your development machine:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

And *never* suppress errors using `@`. Well there are some situations where you can use `@`, but this really isn't one of them.